# Rails routes and querystring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes, query-string

I am having troubles trying to define the correct route for a query coming from ember. The request appears like this:

```
GET "/users?id=1011
```

No matter what I try I always have the request forwarded to the index action, while it is intended for the show action. 
I have tried many things, like

```
get "/users?id=", to: redirect('/users')
```

but nothing seems to work.
Can anyone explain to me what can I do and most important the reason behind it?
Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET /users?id=1011` always goes to index because Rails just sees the route as `GET /users`. The question mark denotes a parameter, which isn't part of any of your defined routes.

You can modify your index method to interpret the param, something like:

```
def index
  if params[:id]
      # call show, do something, whatever
  else
      # regular index action
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of retrieving just one user, it would be more common to route this to your show action as you originally intended. To accomplish this, do not pass the id as a query param, but instead as a slug segment `/users/1011`, which you can accomplish by declaring the following in your routes.rb:

```
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

If you want to go full tilt then you might as well just declare users as a resource like so:

```
resources :users
```

Which will automatically wire up your index, show, update, destroy, etc. Throw [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in the mix and you can have Ember Data start talking to your API nearly "out of the box".